# Wiring 3x PIR Motion Sensors to 1x LED RGB strip which a remote override?

Tags: electrical

Before I go down the route of using a aurdino and coding I was wondering if I could hardwire instead.

**Primary goal:**  Install 3x PIR motion sensors around my bed frame and link up to 1x LED strip so when anyone on any side of the bed trips the motion sensor the whole bed lights up at once and shut off at once.

**Secondly goal:**  Be able to use a remote for RGB capability as well as to override the sensor so I can leave it on over night as needed.

Amazon has a motion sensor with RGB capability and a remote however it only has once motion sensor.  My last resort is to build and code and Arduino however that will likely take much longer and cost me more in the long run.

The PIR motion sensor I would like to use is https://www.ledsupply.com/accessories/pir-motion-sensor-switch.  I asked if I could daisy chain them and the person adamantly said no, when I inquired again I was told yes but not told how.

Answer (score 0):

For just on/off control (no colors), you can chain them with those single-output PIR modules, well, more of a ladder than a daisy chain: they all have to be in parallel.

I don't see how one could easily/reliably mash together consumer-targeted modules to have both PIR(s) and the remote work together. You would need the remote/led controller in front of the power-switches, then switch the common rail of the RGB LEDs on/off. But you usually don't know when buying from amazon et al if your LED strip will be common anode(+) or common cathode(-), and those need different handling. Most 3-channel analog RGB LED strip i've seen is common anode, sinking the separate grounds to turn on, and who knows whether that PIR module switches the positive or negative. If you can find the right matches it *could* work. You'll still have to splice in the PIRs into the strip between the strip and RGB controller, so it's not turnkey. W/O colors, it's a lot simpler.

Arduino is way cheaper and more flexible though, and empowering; never heard anyone regret learning it. DIY, a remote is like $3, RGB strip is <$2/m for 60/m addressable, little PIR sensors are $1 each, and the "Arduino" MCU that ties them all together is under $3 (ex wemos d1, ESP32, etc). Those MCUs both bring wifi to the table for precise scheduled times via NTP, app/webapp control, smart home integration, etc. And you can really customize the heck out of it, say turning your footpath dimly red upon motion between 2-7am for 3 mins then fading to black over 90 seconds. It's actually easier than most folks think, and a ton of fun once you get going.

Comment: thank you so much, I will just start off with just the PIR modules.  how would one wire a ladder in parallel?

Comment: Wire it with just one PIR and your LEDs and make sure it's working. Then add more PIRs by connecting the same wires on the first PIR to the same points on the additional ones (all the input+, all the input-, all the output+, all the output-). You can use, for example power+: 3 wires from the power source to each PIR, or a wire from power+ to pir1, pir1-pir2, pir2-pir3; it's the same topology, electrically speaking. Using a multimeter continuity, each labeled terminal should beep with the same terminal on other PIRs.